# Aspect ratio and viewport with Android : Need an explication

Tags: java, android, libgdx

first I know that is subject that already have many topics but I still don't understand anything.

I'm trying to make games for Android (downloadable on Play Store) but I have a single problem that stop me everytime, how can can I make a game that can be played on every phones with the same aspect ratio ?

For exemple :
I want to make a game where some object fall from the top of the screen randomly on the caractere of the player.

How can I print a background image, a player image and a falling object image that as the same aspect on every phones ?

First I want to print the bakcground image
Here is what I currently have :

```
public class MyAwesomeGame extends Game {
    public SpriteBatch batch;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        setScreen(new MenuScreen(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

And :

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen {

    private MyAwesomeGame game;

    public MenuScreen(MyAwesomeGame game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {}

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}
}
```

Please can someone explain to me what I should do or give me some codes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) is actually what you need. If you want the image with the same aspect ratio for every device you could use `StretchViewport` this will automatically scale down/up your image based on the device aspect ratio but it will lower the image quality.

If you don't want your image quality to be ruined use the FillViewport it also keeps the aspect ratio of the virtual screen size, but in contrast to FitViewport, it will always fill the whole screen which might result in parts of the viewport being cut off.

If you want your background image to take up the whole screen then do something like these:

```
int width =  Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); \\ get the width of the device
int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); \\ get the height of the device

Texture backgroundImage = new Texture(pathName);
Image image = new Image(backgroundImage);
image.setSize(width,height);  \\ background image will fill up your whole screen

Image player = new Image(new Texture(pathname)); \\ it's the same as what we did above

Stage stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(width,height));
stage.addActor(player);  \\ add your player and background image to stage
stage.addActor(image);
```

Click this [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) for more information about `Stage`
The two parameter in `StretchViewport` will stretch the width and height base on the aspect ratio of the device.

Now on your render method update and render your image.

```
   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
     Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     stage.act();
     stage.draw();
}
```

I hope this help!

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah it helped me greatly now my game work just fine on every devices I have :D the last thing I need is learn how to create personalized buttons to make a menu that rocks and I will have finished my first game on Android

Comment: @lan i think there is a mistake.  Device width and height is calculate by Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and Gdx.graphics.getHeight() not from image.getWidth() and image.getHeight().

Comment: @Abhishek Aryan you're right I must've confused when using tiled map because you can't set the size of tiledMap to fill up the whole screen and I have use tilemap size to stretchViewport. I might be wrong, though. Thanks for the correction. I edited it

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Viewports are used for.

The viewport will handle the different resolutions. [See the Viewport wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) for different types of viewports and the differences between them.

There are also some tutorials that can get you started with viewports. 
[GameFromScratch](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-17-Viewports.aspx) has one, but there is also a lot more out there on viewports.

Comment: I have two questions on the tutorial of GameFromScratch : when they use "new FitViewPort(cam,100,100);" what are the "100" ? Is it the size of the picture ? And are they in pixel ?